# accessing the particular field in the json file using jquery Template

Tags: json, jquery

```
$.getJSON('dat.js', function(i,data) {
             $( "#lessons" ).tmpl( data[1].title ).appendTo( "#result" );
            });
```

my json file

```
{

            "posts": [
                    {
                    "title": "ajax | Programming ",
                    "url": "hello"
                    },
                    {
                    "title": "jQuery and Ajax Demos Pard - 3",
                    "url": "how are you"
                    },
                    ]
}
```

i want to access the name field but data[0] is showing error as undefined,

Comment: Your JSON seems invlaid. Keys must be wrapped in quotes, so each object looks like `{"Name" : "Foo", "ReleaseYear" : "Bar"}`. Use JSONLint.com to validate JSON strings.

Comment: And must not be end with `;` symbol.

Comment: @Arnab: Now that you've edited your question to add the quotes around the keys, your script should work fine. If that is the case, I request you to undo your edit, so it is helpful to others in the future.

Comment: ya definitely i will do the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON seems invalid. Keys must be wrapped in quotes, so each object looks like

```
{"Name" : "Foo", "ReleaseYear" : "Bar"}
```

Use [JSONLint.com](http://jsonlint.com) to validate JSON strings.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QMPM7/4/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var test = '[{ "Name": "The Red Violin", "ReleaseYear": "1998" },{ "Name": "Eyes Wide Shut", "ReleaseYear": "1999" },{ "Name": "The Inheritance", "ReleaseYear": "1976" }]';

var obj = JSON.parse(test);
console.log(obj[0].Name);

});​
```